# Disable swipe for specific tab

Tags: flutter

Say I have a tab bar that shows three colored screens like so: I want the user to be able to switch between the first two screens  (red and green) by swiping, but only access the third by pressing a button. How's that done? I've tried physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(). But that disables swiping through all screens at the same time.

```
TabBarView(
        controller: tabcontroler,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(color: Colors.red),
          Container(color: Colors.green),
          Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check current tab index and change scroll physics accordingly

`scrollPhysics: index == 2 ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysicys : AnotherScrollPhysics(),`

you can find and use default physics.

Comment: This works, but after trying to swipe, it stops for all pages, even if index different than 2. So you won't be able to go back anymore once you're at the second page